# Append somecode to all links in a div

Tags: jquery, append

I want to append a code after all links with mp3 extension in a specific div.

Here is the code I am trying :

```
$("#Temp_Div").find('a[href$="mp3"]').append('<a class="mp3play" href="javascript:Play('+ $(this).href +');"></a>');
```

The problem is `$(this).href` It doesn't return the href of link. it returns `undefined`

Comment: Usually it should be `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: although it's unconventional to do it that way, it should work to select it that way, which begs the question of what your markup actually looks like

Comment: @m90 no, it should be `this.href`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `this` is a DOM object you should just be using:

```
this.href
```

The (more verbose, less efficient) jQuery way of writing it would be:

```
$(this).attr('href');
```

In any event, the `.append()` call won't work as written because `this` isn't actually being set at all.

You need to call `.each()` with the matched elements with a callback function.  jQuery will then ensure that `this` is set to the current DOM object.

Like this:

```
$("#Temp_Div").find('a[href$="mp3"]').each(function() {
    $(this).append('<a class="mp3play" href="javascript:Play('+ this.href +');" />');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

href is an attribute so you have to use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function, example:

```
$("#Temp_Div").find('a[href$="mp3"]').each(function() { $(this).append('<a class="mp3play" href="javascript:Play('+ $(this).attr('href') +');"></a>'); });
```

Your can review the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$("#Temp_Div").find('a[href$="mp3"]').each(function() {
    $(this).after('<a class="mp3play" href="javascript:Play('+ this.href +');"></a>');
});
```

`this` will refer to the a tag. (You don't need to wrap it in a jquery object to get the href)

I think you also want to use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) rather than [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) as this will add the link after the other link rather than inside it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FBJHQ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try $(this).attr('href') instead, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.href` if the element is anchor